# Как включить поддержку std::format и прочих обновлений стандартной библиотеки с++20 в gcc?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++20

Столкнулся с проблемой, что несмотря на поддержку таких вещей как корутины gcc не поддерживает абсолютное большинство функций стандартной библиотеки, есть ли способ это исправить?

Comment: можно отправить свой патчик с реализацией `std::format` в libstdc++... ну или дождаться пока кто-то другой это сделает...

Comment: да, просто людей не хватает... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20